# Documenting module/class/function bodies in Python Sphinx docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is there a way with Sphinx documentation to output a function or class body (the code itself) with the autodoc feature? I'm using autodoc to much success. In addition to the docstrings getting pulled in to the documentation I want like a link to click for each function where it will show you the source... is that possible?

This is about what most of my documentation looks like now:

```
.. module:`foo.mymodule`

Title
===================


.. automodule:: foo.mymodule

.. autoclass:: MyModulesClass
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this still matters: The [viewcode extension](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/ext/viewcode.html) can do this, but needs the development version (1.0) of Sphinx

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.  Autodoc is only for pulling the documentation out of the source code.